# Call method of abstract super class without using sub class object

Tags: java, overloading

Suppose there is an abstract Super class with only one method which has default implementation. Now, sub class is extending super class and it overrides the method of super class.

How to call method of super class without using sub class object?

```
public abstract class SuperClass
{
    public void test()
    {
      System.out.println("SuperClass test method called");
    }
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass
{
    public void test()
    {
      System.out.println("SubClass test method called");
    }
}

public class CallAbstract
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        //How to Call abtract SuperClass test method without using sub class object?
     }
}
```

Comment: `SuperClass extends BaseClass`  ..shouldn't that logically be `SubClass extends BaseClass`?

Comment: Yes, the example is counterintuitive

Comment: By the way, where is the `abstract` part of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using another anonymous class you could do:

```
public class CallAbstract
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      (new BaseClass(){ }).test();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Edwin. Tried ur code. but one doubt, if we can't create instance of abstract class then how come we can write new BaseClass() code. Please elaborate little

Comment: because the following `{ }` creates an anonymous subclass that overwrites no methods at all. So he's not instantiating the abstract class, but the class that extends `BaseClass` but has no name.

Comment: That is correct, as jlordo says, the expression `new BaseClass(){}` is defining a new class inline, and at the same point, creating an instance of it. Since this new inline class does not override the `test` method, if you invoke it you get the original BaseClass implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You need another **Subclass** that does not overwrite the `test()` method.

```
public class OtherSubClass extends BaseClass {

}
```

And in your `main` method:

```
OtherSubClass osc = new OtherSubClass();
osc.test();
```

or use an anonymous class, like Edwin Dalorzo suggests.